# Searching for numerical values in java structures

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a homework to do, which is really interesting and I found that I've no idea how to implement data structure that should be search-able and relatively fast. 
There is given a database, with 3 fields - x,y,z. They are in fact values of some unknown function, that represents 3d coordinates. I have to find plain areas in the set of data. I wonder, what is the best way to temporarily store these co-ordinates in my program. I would prefer to make a class called "Point", with the appropriate fields and store them in one of collection types (HashMap? ArrayList? LinkedList?) That could allow me to implement some methods inside file like "search for neighbours with same height". But i believe that there should be much faster data structure which stores the co-ordinates directly instead of packaging the co-ordinates into an object. 
But other side... damn, I'm learning OOP :) 
What is best structure to keep data in this case?
Thanks
Smok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coordinates means **direct access**. If you want to be able to access a member of the data structure by index, **ArrayList** is the way to go.

Why not HashMash? Maps are suitable for key-value pairs, and your structure contains only values.

Why not LinkedList? It's suitable for traversing from one item to the next, but very slow for direct access.

Comment: I see what you mean. But my dataset consist of three values (x,y,z). Is there a way to store them directly into an ArrayList? I've been doing this by creating an objects and storing values in it's fields, like mentioned in question. That objects have been storred in an array list. Don't know how to implement direct access. Could you please explain it to me?

Comment: Read the ArrayList JavaDocs. That ought to give you all the information you need. Be sure to check what version of Java you're running.

Answer (score 1):

I think neo4J could be the answer. Please google for it.

Comment: It could be great, but I forgot to mention - no external libs are allowed :|

Comment: This is side stepping to *biased opinion territory* but neo4j is essentially GPL software making it very unhealthy anyway to use for anything serious (unless you want to be the next Red Hat). They seem to have really good marketing though and I suppose the software is good too for its purpose which is why people keep recommending it.